# Value of second last digit

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How can I find the second last digit of the number $7^{41^{17}+1}$? I'm not quite sure how to start. A hint would suffice. Thanks!

Comment: work mod $100$. Euler's theorem can be helpful.

Comment: $7^4 = 2401$ is a helpful bit of knowledge to have for this problem.

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362012/find-the-last-two-digits-of-781

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate $7^{41^{17}+1} \pmod {100}$ then read off the leading digit from the result.  You do that the same way you did in [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338729/question-on-modular-arithmetic).  Euler's theorem again.

Comment: Thank you! I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see ...

$7^1=7, 7^2=49, 7^3=343, 7^4=2401, ...$

Hmmm, of $7^4$ ends with $01$, what does that say about $7^8, 7^{12}, 7^{any.multiple.of.4}$?

$41^{17}-1$ is easily seen to be a multiple of $4$.  Then $7$ to that power ends with $01$ and multiying by $7^2=49$ implies $7^{41^{17}+1}$ ends with ... .

Got it?